# Problems while making requests to a flask restful app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restful

I have the following flask api, which just returns echo of its input:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class query(Resource):

    def get(self, a_string):
        return{
        'original': a_string,
        'echo': a_string
        }

api.add_resource(query,'/echo/<a_string>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then, when I try to use python requests to make queries to my api:

```
import json
def query(text):    
    payload = {'echo': str(text)}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.request("POST", 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r)
    #data = json.loads(r.text)
    #return data

query('hi')
```

I keep getting:

```
<Response [404]>
```

Any idea of how to fix this issue? Interestingly when I go to my browser and do:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/echo/hi
```

I get:

```
{"original": "hi", "echo": "hi"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But sending a POST to / with a payload of {"echo": whatever} is not at all the same as sending a GET to /echo/whatever. Your API expects the latter.

```
def query(text):
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/echo/{}".format(text))
```

Or, change your API so it does expect that:

```
class query(Resource):

    def post(self):
        a_string = request.form["echo"]
        return {
            'original': a_string,
            'echo': a_string
        }

api.add_resource(query, '/')
```

Comment: could you improve your answer? there are some syntaxis mistakes THANKS for the help